# Видовое понятие, следующее за родовым - собственное или нарицательное?

Tags: ономастика

Боевой порядок каре.

Следует ли давать "Каре" в кавычках? Довольно часто определение слова как имени собственного или нарицательного представляет затруднения. Как разобраться?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: Боевой порядок каре.

**Каре** — боевой порядок пехоты, построенной в виде квадрата, то есть частный вид боевого порядка. Кавычки не нужны.

Здесь все имена **нарицательные**, но между существительными *порядок* (род) и *каре* (вид)  существуют **родо-видовые отношения** (сравнить: птица воробей).

Answer (score 0):

> Следует ли давать "Каре" в кавычках?

Контекст нужен. Использование родовидового понятия характерно более для научного стиля, там кавычки обычно не нужны. Но если это впервые вводимое понятие (в значении: *такой боевой порядок называется "каре"*), кавычки вполне уместны.
В остальных же случаях использование полного родовидового понятия обычно избыточно.

> Довольно часто определение слова как имени собственного или
> нарицательного представляет затруднения. Как разобраться?

Вообще-то это другой вопрос, с кавычками связан лишь косвенно.
Но по сути "каре" - имя нарицательное, хотя имеет некоторые признаки собственного. ***Стрижка "Каре"*** - название стрижки, ***стрижка каре*** - её тип.